# Jersey Test Framework & HK2-Guice bridge

Tags: java, guice, jersey-2.0, hk2, jersey-test-framework

There are REST web service based on Jersey 2.23.2 & Guice 3.0. To use Guice it is necessary to adjust the [hk2-guice bridge](https://javaee.github.io/hk2/guice-bridge.html) (I'm using 2.5.0-b07). Everything works fine until I have tried to test the service using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.23.2/test-framework.html). Can't configure hk2-guice bridge for tests.

My test:

```
public class SomeTest extends JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerClassTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return super.configure(); // cant't configure
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

I can't configure test in `SomeTest.configure()` just returning `new JerseyConfiguration()` (see below) because JerseyConfiguration's constructor expected ServiceLocator's object.

Even if it were possible to return an object of class `JerseyConfiguration` - I'm not sure that my test would work because some filters and listener are defined in the web.xml file.

**How to configure the test taking into account all filters, listener and hk2-guice bridge?**

---

Web service details

Dependencies section from build.gradle:

```
def jerseyVersion = '2.23.2'
def hk2Version = '2.5.0-b07'
def giuceVersion = '3.0'

dependencies {
    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
    //jersey
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:${jerseyVersion}"
    compile "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:${jerseyVersion}"
    //hk2
    compile "org.glassfish.hk2:guice-bridge:${hk2Version}"
    //guice
    compile "com.google.inject:guice:${giuceVersion}"
    compile "com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:${giuceVersion}"
}
```

File web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>REST API App</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.core.JerseyGuiceServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.core.JerseyConfiguration</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jerseyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Class JerseyGuiceServletContextListener:

```
public class JerseyGuiceServletContextListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    static Injector injector;

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new JerseyServletModuleConfig());
        return injector;
    }
}
```

Class JerseyServletModuleConfig:

```
class JerseyServletModuleConfig extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        bind(HeyResource.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }
}
```

Class JerseyConfiguration:

```
package com.example.core;

import com.google.inject.Injector;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceBridge;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceIntoHK2Bridge;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    @Inject
    public JerseyConfiguration(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, ServletContext servletContext) {
        packages("com.example.ws");
         GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
         GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
         guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(JerseyGuiceServletContextListener.injector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just overrode `configureDeployment()` & modified `configure()` methods in test

```
public class SomeTest extends JerseyTestNg.ContainerPerClassTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() throws TestContainerException {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

@Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .packages("com.example.ws")
                .register(GensonCustomResolver.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        Application application = configure();

        return ServletDeploymentContext.builder(application)
                .addListener(JerseyGuiceServletContextListener.class)
                .addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "guiceFilter")
                .addFilter(ServletContainer.class, "jerseyFilter", new HashMap<String, String>(){{
                    put("javax.ws.rs.Application", JerseyConfiguration.class.getCanonicalName());
                }})
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

& add web.xml to test classpath.