# Jersey test dependency injection with Guice

Tags: java, jersey, guice

I am unable to use JerseyTest (v2.25) together with Guice dependency injection. My current setup is inspired by an answer on another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39225187/jersey-test-framework-hk2-guice-bridge). This setup still tries to wire dependency of `@Provides` annotated classes through HK2, failing my test case. If I remove the `.packages()` invocation from my test `ResourceConfig` it seems the listener is not initialized at all and my test cases all return 404's.

This is my current jersey-test setup:

```java
public class MyTestSuite extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig().packages("com.example.api");
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
        return ServletDeploymentContext.builder(configure())
                .addListener(GuiceConfig.class)
                .addFilter(GuiceFilter.class, "guiceFilter")
                .addFilter(ServletContainer.class, "jerseyFilter", Collections.singletonMap("javax.ws.rs.Application", JerseyConfig.class.getName()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here are the classes referenced in the deployment context:

```java
public class GuiceConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
    static Injector injector;

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new WebModule());
        return injector;
    }
}
```

```java
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    @Inject
    public JerseyConfig(ServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
        Injector injector = (Injector) serviceLocator.getService(ServletContext.class).getAttribute(Injector.class.getName());
        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
        serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class).bridgeGuiceInjector(injector.createChildInjector(new HK2IntoGuiceBridge(serviceLocator)));
        packages("com.example.api");
    }
}
```

```java
public class WebModule extends ServletModule {

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        serve("/*").with(ServletContainer.class, Collections.singletonMap(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyConfig.class.getName()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of writing your own, You can use existing library [Jersey Guice Module](https://github.com/logzio/guice-jersey)

> you need to bridge the gap between the two DI frameworks. This module aims to do just that by booting Jetty based Jersey server and initializing the bridge between HK2 and Guice.
>
> **Getting Started**
>
> - Add JerseyModule to your Guice Injector
> - Configure packages to scan for resources and a port to expose
> - Get instance of JerseyServer and start consuming your Restful resources

```
 compile 'io.logz:guice-jersey:1.0.8'
```

Notice you are missing [GuiceIntoHK2Bridge](https://github.com/logzio/guice-jersey/blob/master/src/main/java/io/logz/guice/jersey/GuiceJerseyResourceConfig.java)

> ```
> Injector injector = (Injector) servletContext.getAttribute(Injector.class.getName()); 
> GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
> GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
> guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
> ```

Comment: How would I use `guice-jersey` in combination with jersey-test (inmemory)?